# Does TRUNCATE TABLE affects isolation level in Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, transaction, truncate, isolation-level

As I am working on the project which has SQL SERVER  as a database....I'm maintaining isolation level in my project where I enabled snapshot isolation level for my project....

As I have to make some dirty read, I am querying it with setting `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED.`.I've implemented it in stored proc...Here is short version of my stored proc

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_ReadDirtyData]
@id INT,
@mode VARCHAR(5)

AS
BEGIN
    --Read Dirty Data
    IF (@mode = 'RDD')
    BEGIN
            SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
            SELECT * FROM tbl_transaction
            WHERE id = @id;--@id foreign key in tbl_transaction.
                           --This read has been done during the transaction from C# Apps
    END
END
```

In my C# apps, following structure is maintained

```
snapshot transaction start

stage1 : tblmaster --generates id
stage2 :tblchild --inserts the data with above id as foreign key.After successfull inserting,
          --dirty read goes here applying where equal to above id for other operation

if(operationSuccessful)
{
     transactionCommit()
}
else
{
     transactionRollback();
}

snapshot transaction end
```

I am getting problem in stage2 after TRUNCATE operation on operated table...

I've been checking whether it makes correct dirty reads,so I used to clear the data of that specific table where dirty read has been occured...

But, the problem comes when I use `TRUNCATE` for clearing the table data....If I use `TRUNCATE`, I can't make dirty reads where as if I use `DELETE`, it perfectly works for dirty read....

Here, I want to make clear that I'm not making dirty read during TRUNCATE/DELETE operation...After TRUNCATE/DELETE operation only, I go for dirty read of fresh data......

Now, I'm curious that whether `TRUNCATE` affects internal isolation of that table or not....

Comment: Is there any reason to downvote the question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`TRUNCATE` table will take a `SCH-M` lock on the table.

Even at `READ UNCOMMITTED` level the `SELECT` query will need to take a `SCH-S` lock. This won't be possible until the `TRUNCATE` transaction has ended and the  conflicting `SCH-M` lock has been released.

Comment: Thanx for the reply....I've no problem during TRUNCATE operation....After Truncate operation made on that table, the READ UNCOMMITTED doesn't work..... But if I made Delete operation instead of TRUNCATE, dirty reads can be done....

Comment: @LolCoder - `DELETE` doesn't take a `SCH-M` lock on the table. It will take `X` locks on rows, pages, extents or even the whole object. That doesn't conflict with the `SCH-S` lock needed for the read. The only thing that blocks `SCH-S` is `SCH-M`. See [Lock compatibility matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186396(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: I've updated the question..Please have a glance on updated question.....

Comment: The update doesn't make any difference to this answer or preceding comment. Are you still unclear as to why `TRUNCATE` causes blocking and `DELETE` doesn't?

Comment: Sorry if I couldn't make the question clear....I don't have any issue with lock....I would just like to know whether TRUNCATE clears all the information along with data which DELETE wouldn't clears...From my experience, TRUNCATE had perform much operation on table than DELETE....

Comment: Your question was about why `TRUNCATE` doesn't work with dirty reads not general differences between the two. Other differences apart from locking is that `TRUNCATE` is minimally logged so for large tables is likely to be quicker than `DELETE`. `TRUNCATE` deallocates the last page in the table and `DELETE` doesn't.

Comment: Final update on question...If it really clears question,please update on your answer.....already +1 from me....